# webpack not reading webpack-config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

I can't understand why webpack-config.js is not being read in my project.

If I make some syntax error in webpack-config.js it won't even show the error.

Here is **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "ff",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot --progress --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my **webpack-config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');

const conf = {
    entry: './src/index.js', 
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'), 
        filename: 'main.js', 
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    }, 
    devServer: {
        overlay:true
    }
};

module.exports = conf;
```

Comment: can you provide whole of error trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably you have used a wrong file name - webpack is looking for "webpack.config.js" file, but you have "webpack-config.js" (dash instead of dot). Try renaming or help webpack to find it by explicitly setting your config path using [--config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) option

Comment: you are absolutely right :)) thanks, i renamed filename and everything works well